# Is etymology the best way or a good way to build Latin vocabulary?

Tags: vocabulary, etymology, book

I heard that the best way to improve English vocabulary is from the etymology's perspective. That refers to a lot of prefixes and roots that originated in Latin and Greek.

Is etymology also the best way or a good way to build Latin vocabulary?

What books are good for building Latin vocabulary, whether from the perspective of etymology or not? Thanks.

Comment: I would recommend *extensive reading* as a possible approach. Though it works better for live languages, where one can choose reading more suitable for one's level (classics might be hard, but junk literature - like detective novels, love stories, fantasy or whatever one likes is abundant and accessible.)

Answer (score 1):

**Humans learn best by connecting new information to existing information in a variety of ways, and paying attention to etymology is a good way to contribute to that.**

It's a little unclear what you mean by etymology being a 'way to build Latin vocabulary'. But there is no question that by considering related words within Latin and outside Latin, you will help yourself learn Latin vocabulary more effectively.

For example, Latin has many verbs that are formed by adding prefixes (*re-*, *de-*, *ad-* etc.) to verbs. Breaking them down helps you link them together in a family of related words (e.g. *renuntio*, *denuntio*, *annuntio*) rather than learning them as separate individual tokens.

You can also use your familiarity with English and any other languages you know to link Latin words to their relations. For example, *caldus* is related to the Italian *caldo* and the English *scald* (not the 'false friend' *cold*!). Many of the more memorable etymologies involve vivid imagery, like the English *recalcitrant* 'stubborn, difficult' from the Latin *recalcitro* ultimately from *calx* 'heel', evoking a horse kicking back with its heels.

**Using resources like a good dictionary, incorporate etymology into your regular learning, rather than trying to specifically learn etymology.**

You ask what books are good for building Latin vocabulary – for this I would first suggest any good Latin teaching material, which should introduce words gradually and will generally be written with the aim of building up to a practical working vocabulary. Beyond this, simply reading and looking up words as you go (perhaps even writing your own vocabulary list with what you've looked up) is valuable. We remember most effectively what we use regularly, so it's not helpful to try to 'cram' lots of words if you are not coming across them in your reading or composition.

There are books about etymology, whether etymological dictionaries or more popular books filled with particularly interesting examples. I can recommend them for interest, but I wouldn't read one expecting to learn a large body of specific new words.